# Can I use Django ORM’s update function as a mutex?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I want to ensure that a given notification is only sent once, even if two instances of the task are running at the same time (the tasks are running in Celery and might be restarted automatically). Here’s what I am doing:

```
    with transaction.atomic():
        update_count = (Notification.objects
            .filter(id=notification.id, was_sent=None)
            .update(was_sent=timezone.now()))
        if update_count == 1:
            self.send_message(notification)
```

The idea is that the `UPDATE` command this turns into at the SQL level succeeds only if `was_sent` is null beforehand—and that this is atomic so if another process is trying to do the same thing at the same instant, one will succeed (`update_count==1`) and the other will fail (`update_count==0`).

The wrapping in `transaction.atomic()` is in order to roll back the update if the message fails. I don’t expect it to affect the atomicity of the `UPDATE` itself.

Despite this I am seeing the effects of the `send_message` function duplicated in a small percentage of cases. Am I wrong to assume that other processes will "see" the update immediately?

Django 1.6, PostgreSQL 9.2.6

Comment: My reading of the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/transaction-iso.html) for the default read committed transaction isolation level is that you are correct - this shouldn't happen. That said, I'm even more sure it will work if you get rid of the transaction, so if you're desperate you can find some other mechanism to deal with message sending problems.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry, a qs update may be splited in several operations: get model ids to be update, update database rows. In non repeatable read scenario, two processes can read nulls from database and write non empty values back to this fields. It isn't?

Comment: @pdc, you can declare database [for twice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) in second declaration set isolation level to [serializable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/databases/#isolation-level), then set `using` parameter into `atomic` decorator to perform operation with high isolation level.

Comment: @danihp: Is it true that "a qs update may be split into several operations"? The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) implies otherwise: "Performs an SQL update query for the specified fields". Perhaps the OP can tell us the actual SQL generated for the query...

Comment: @pdc, have you solved this issue? Have you tested anything else?